# java method returning a huge list of same json data

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a method like this

```
@ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getGroupList", produces = "application/json")
    public Map getGroups() {
        List<UserGroup> userGroups = userGroupService.getAllUserGroups();
        Map result = new TreeMap();
        result.put("groupList", userGroups);
        return result;
    }
```

When I am loading the page /getGroupList its returning a very long json data. When I debug the code I can clearly see that in usreGroups list there are just 2 items. Why method getGroups returing huge data. Also the returned data is ending with with double qoutes and it looks like its till incomplete...

Comment: What is a `UserGroup`? Do you have circular references?

Comment: Yes. It has objects which further contain objects

Answer (score 0):

This is an assumption. If your `UserGroup` class is something like

```
class UserGroup {
    User user;
    Group group;
}
```

And those classes are like

```
class User {
    UserGroup userGroup;
}
class Group {
    UserGroup userGroup;
}
```

Then the serialization process will go on forever as serializing a `UserGroup` will attempt to serialize the `User`, which will try to re-serialize the same `UserGroup` and so on...

Spring uses Jackson by default to serialize to JSON. Jackson has a number of solutions for this, such as `@JsonBackReference`.